# ASP.NET Core RedirectToAction doesn't exit function?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have the following snippet

```
        if (hasRegistrations)
        {
            RedirectToAction("Manage");
        }

        return View();
```

Even thought `RedirectToAction` is executed, the execution still flows to `return View();`

How should this be handled correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to `return RedirectToAction("Manage");`

**Explanation:**

The `RedirectToAction` method returns `RedirectToRouteResult` rather than immediately returning a HTTP redirect response. So you have to `return` the `RedirectToRouteResult` from the controller action. In your example execution is continuing and `return View()` is being run instead.